# Efficiency of dict.get() method

Tags: python, methods, dictionary, get

I have just started learning python and worried that if I use dict.get(key,default_value) or I define my own method for it....so do they have any differences:

[1st method]:

```
dict={}
for c in string:
    if c in dict:
        dict[c]+=1
    else:
        dict[c]=1
```

and the other dict.get() method that python provides

```
for c in string:
    dict[c]=dict.get(c,0)+1
```

do they have any differences on efficiency or speed...or they are just the same and 2nd one only saves writing few more lines of code...

Comment: For counting for keys, use `collections.Counter` objects instead..

Comment: You can also use `collections.defaultdict(int)` here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this specific case, use either a [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) or a [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object instead:

```
import collections

dct = collections.defaultdict(int)

for c in string:
     dict[c] += 1
```

or

```
dct = collections.Counter(string)
```

Both are subclasses of the standard `dict` type. The `Counter` type adds some more helpful functionality like summing two counters or listing the most common entities that have been counted. The `defaultdict` class can also be given other default types; use `defaultdict(list)` for example to collect things into lists per key.

When you want to compare performance of two different approaches, you want to use the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def intest(dct, values):
...     for c in values:
...         if c in dct:
...             dct[c]+=1
...         else:
...             dct[c]=1
... 
>>> def get(dct, values):
...     for c in values:
...         dct[c] = dct.get(c, 0) + 1
... 
>>> values = range(10) * 10
>>> timeit.timeit('test(dct, values)', 'from __main__ import values, intest as test; dct={}')
22.210275888442993
>>> timeit.timeit('test(dct, values)', 'from __main__ import values, get as test; dct={}')
27.442166090011597
```

This shows that using `in` is a little faster.

There is, however, a *third* option to consider; catching the `KeyError` exception:

```
>>> def tryexcept(dct, values):
...     for c in values:
...         try:
...             dct[c] += 1
...         except KeyError:
...             dct[c] = 1
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('test(dct, values)', 'from __main__ import values, tryexcept as test; dct={}')
18.023509979248047
```

which happens to be the fastest, because only 1 in 10 cases are for a new key.

Last but not least, the two alternatives I proposed:

```
>>> def default(dct, values):
...     for c in values:
...         dct[c] += 1
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('test(dct, values)', 'from __main__ import values, default as test; from collections import defaultdict; dct=defaultdict(int)')
15.277361154556274
>>> timeit.timeit('Counter(values)', 'from __main__ import values; from collections import Counter')
38.657804012298584
```

So the `Counter()` type is slowest, but `defaultdict` is *very* fast indeed. `Counter()`s do a lot more work though, and the extra functionality can bring ease of development and execution speed benefits elsewhere.

Comment: very great functionality it is off course....but again the same question...if it only saves few/much coding or it is more efficient in other ways too?
if yes then what are the other fields in which it is more efficient?

Comment: @user1977504: Test it yourself with the `timeit` module. :-)